# JavaFX not rendering earlier items in an array, unable to find issue, believe threading might be the issue

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, bresenham

I wrote a line drawing algorithm that functions correctly when calculating each point, however when it gets rendered the program skips nearly 20 points, unable to find the issue.

I have tried to mess with the algorithm, specifically the for loop that adds the points to the positions list where the line gets calculated as I have had problems with that in other versions of the code. I just cannot for the life of me find the issue with the code, I am pretty new to Java as you will probably tell from the mess of code below. It says not to post an entire file but I am unable to pinpoint where it is going wrong. I am so incredibly sorry for the mess of code below I just am at that point where I have no clue what is wrong.

```
package sample;

import com.sun.jdi.ArrayReference;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class PositionCounter {
    public int position;

    public void setPosition(int newPos){
        position = newPos;
    }
}

public class Main extends Application {

//    public void drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Stage primStage, GraphicsContext gc){
//        drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2 , primStage, gc);
//        drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, primStage, gc);
//        drawLine(x1, y1, x1 , y2, primStage, gc);
//        drawLine(x2, y1, x2 , y2, primStage, gc);
//        drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1 , primStage, gc);
//
//    }
//

    public void fillPosition(ArrayList<Integer[]> points, GraphicsContext gc, int positionInArray ){
        gc.fillRect(points.get(positionInArray)[0], points.get(positionInArray)[1], squareWidth / 2, squareWidth / 2);
        //System.out.println("(" + points.get(positionInArray)[0] + ", " + points.get(positionInArray)[1]);
    }

    public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Stage primStage, GraphicsContext gc){

        ArrayList<Integer[]> points = calculateLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, gc);
        PositionCounter position = new PositionCounter();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                    Runnable updater = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            fillPosition(points, gc, position.position);

                        }
                    };

                    int dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
                    int dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
                    int m = (dy >= dx) ? dy : dx;

                    for (int i = 0; i <= points.size(); i++) {

                        position.setPosition(i);

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(20);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }

                        Platform.runLater(updater);

                    }


            }
        });

        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        //STUFF
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.setFill(Color.GOLD);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        //////////

        gc.fillRect(0, 200, 400, 1);
        gc.fillRect(0, 100, 400, 1);
        gc.fillRect(0, 300, 400, 1);
        gc.fillRect(200, 0, 1, 400);
        gc.fillRect(100, 0, 1, 400);
        gc.fillRect(300, 0, 1, 400);


       // drawRectangle(50, 50, 350, 250, primaryStage, gc);


        //drawLine(50, 250, 350, 250 , primaryStage, gc);
        //drawLine(50, 50, 350, 250, primaryStage, gc);
        //drawLine(50, 50, 50 , 250, primaryStage, gc);
        //drawLine(350, 50, 350 , 250, primaryStage, gc);
        drawLine(50, 50, 350, 50 , primaryStage, gc);



        //////////
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        /////////
    }

    int squareWidth = 2;

    public ArrayList<Integer[]> calculateLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, GraphicsContext gc){

        ArrayList<Integer[]> points = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

        int dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
        int dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);

        int sx = (x1 < x2) ? 1 : -1;
        int sy = (y1 < y2) ? 1 : -1;

        int err = dx-dy;
        int x = x1;
        int y = y1;
        int e2 = 0;

        Integer[] pos = new Integer[2];
        pos[0] = x;
        pos[1] = y;
        points.add(pos);

        int m = (dy >= dx) ? dy  : dx ;

        for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {

                e2 = 2 * err;
                if (e2 > -dy) {
                    err = err - dy;
                    x = x + sx;
                    Integer[] position = new Integer[2];
                    position[0] = x;
                    position[1] = y;
                    points.add(position);
                }

                if (e2 < dx) {
                    err = err + dx;
                    y = y + sy;
                    Integer[] position = new Integer[2];
                    position[0] = x;
                    position[1] = y;
                    points.add(position);
                }

        }

        return points;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the calculate line function returns the correct points, it just doesnt render them properly.

Comment: Okay it seems that the Thread.sleep() function effects the rendering, putting a higher value of milliseconds seems to fix the problem, putting 100 in took away the problem however the speed is just too slow, are there any alternatives?

Comment: What is the purpose of that background `Thread`? It doesn't seem to be doing any hard work.

Comment: I don't understand the `Runnable` inside the `Runnable`?

Comment: @Sedrick Since the logic for the update is the same for all updates, the same `Runnable` object can be reused for all updates. The purpose seems pretty clear to me. @Sam Scheduling the executions of the runnable is done by JavaFX. This results in several issues: The runnable may not run between updates skiping values. Also there is no guarantee that the `PositionCounter` instance both threads see is memory consistent; Lacking the appropriate precaucions the javafx application thread may never see any position but 0.

Comment: Also note that your index equals the size of the list in the end possibly resulting in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Thanks guys so much for all the comments, I am new to Java so everything written here is fantastic feedback, the runnable inside the runnable confused me at first however it worked so I just went along with it, this is obviously a bad way of doing things and after playing around for a while I realised I had used it to put a delay each time a dot was placed to create a drawing effect. Below I was given a fantastic answer that I plan on spending a couple days trying to understand every aspect of the Timeline class. Again, thank you so much for your replies every bit of feedback is useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) instead of [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). It can be done using a `Thread`, but `Timeline` is designed for cases like this.

> Draw Line Method:

```
public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Stage primStage, GraphicsContext gc)
{

    ArrayList<Integer[]> points = calculateLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, gc);
    PositionCounter position = new PositionCounter();

    int dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
    int dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
    int m = (dy >= dx) ? dy : dx;

    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    Timeline animationTimeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), (ActionEvent t) -> {
        position.setPosition(counter.getAndIncrement());
        fillPosition(points, gc, position.position);
    }));
    animationTimeline.setCycleCount(points.size());
    animationTimeline.play();

}
```

> Full Code:

```
import com.sun.jdi.ArrayReference;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.util.Duration;

class PositionCounter
{

    public int position;

    public void setPosition(int newPos)
    {
        position = newPos;
    }
}

public class JavaFXTestingGround extends Application
{

//    public void drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Stage primStage, GraphicsContext gc){
//        drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2 , primStage, gc);
//        drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, primStage, gc);
//        drawLine(x1, y1, x1 , y2, primStage, gc);
//        drawLine(x2, y1, x2 , y2, primStage, gc);
//        drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1 , primStage, gc);
//
//    }
//
    public void fillPosition(ArrayList<Integer[]> points, GraphicsContext gc, int positionInArray)
    {
        gc.fillRect(points.get(positionInArray)[0], points.get(positionInArray)[1], squareWidth / 2, squareWidth / 2);
        //System.out.println("(" + points.get(positionInArray)[0] + ", " + points.get(positionInArray)[1]);
    }

    public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Stage primStage, GraphicsContext gc)
    {

        ArrayList<Integer[]> points = calculateLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, gc);
        PositionCounter position = new PositionCounter();

        int dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
        int dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
        int m = (dy >= dx) ? dy : dx;

        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        Timeline animationTimeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), (ActionEvent t) -> {
            position.setPosition(counter.getAndIncrement());
            fillPosition(points, gc, position.position);
        }));
        animationTimeline.setCycleCount(points.size());
        animationTimeline.play();

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {

        //STUFF
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.setFill(Color.GOLD);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        //////////

        gc.fillRect(0, 200, 400, 1);
        gc.fillRect(0, 100, 400, 1);
        gc.fillRect(0, 300, 400, 1);
        gc.fillRect(200, 0, 1, 400);
        gc.fillRect(100, 0, 1, 400);
        gc.fillRect(300, 0, 1, 400);

        // drawRectangle(50, 50, 350, 250, primaryStage, gc);
        //drawLine(50, 250, 350, 250 , primaryStage, gc);
        //drawLine(50, 50, 350, 250, primaryStage, gc);
        //drawLine(50, 50, 50 , 250, primaryStage, gc);
        //drawLine(350, 50, 350 , 250, primaryStage, gc);
        drawLine(50, 50, 350, 50, primaryStage, gc);

        //////////
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        /////////
    }

    int squareWidth = 2;

    public ArrayList<Integer[]> calculateLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, GraphicsContext gc)
    {

        ArrayList<Integer[]> points = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

        int dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
        int dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);

        int sx = (x1 < x2) ? 1 : -1;
        int sy = (y1 < y2) ? 1 : -1;

        int err = dx - dy;
        int x = x1;
        int y = y1;
        int e2 = 0;

        Integer[] pos = new Integer[2];
        pos[0] = x;
        pos[1] = y;
        points.add(pos);

        int m = (dy >= dx) ? dy : dx;

        for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {

            e2 = 2 * err;
            if (e2 > -dy) {
                err = err - dy;
                x = x + sx;
                Integer[] position = new Integer[2];
                position[0] = x;
                position[1] = y;
                points.add(position);
            }

            if (e2 < dx) {
                err = err + dx;
                y = y + sy;
                Integer[] position = new Integer[2];
                position[0] = x;
                position[1] = y;
                points.add(position);
            }

        }

        return points;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```